# Entering data into TableView using setItems method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to populate my javafx application TableView using setItems method,
while doing so, i first defined my controller path, by doing

> fx:"sample.Application"

then i defined my data model with the class name "Products" with all the necessary constructors and getters and setters. I then started writing my controller code, i defined all the necessary fx: id's with annotation of FXML, I override the initialize method which apparently is giving no errors, also to populate TableView i used ObserverList and called constructor of Products by using observerArrayList, in the end when i try to populate the TableView with fx:id ="table", by using setItems(), i got an error:

> table.setItems(prodList);

error:

> Error:(46, 19) java: identifier expected
>   Error:(46, 28) java: identifier expected

here is the code:

> FXML CODE:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" >
        <columns>                                                                                                               
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_id" text="PRODUCT ID"/>                                                                     
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_name" text="NAME"/>                                                                         
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_price" text="PRICE" />                                                                      
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_tax" text="TAX" />                                                                          
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_discount" text="DISCOUNT" />                                                                
        </columns>                                                                                                              
</TableView>
```

> Controller code

```
public class Application implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Products> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Products, Integer> col_id;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Products, String> col_name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Products, Integer> col_price;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Products, Integer> col_tax;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Products, Integer> col_discount;

    final ObservableList<Products> prodList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Products(11, "Laptop", 25000, 23, 12 )
    );


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("productId"));
        col_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        col_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        col_tax.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tax"));
        col_discount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("discount"));
    }

    table.setItems(prodList); //error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the property value factory in the initialize method. I think that's causing the problem.

There's nothing inside the `PropertyValueFactory<>`. You have to set it the way given below -

```
    col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Products, Integer>("productId"));
    col_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Products, String>("name"));
    col_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Products, Integer>("price"));
    col_tax.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Products, Integer>("tax"));
    col_discount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Products, Integer>("discount"));
```

Another thing, `table.setItems(prodList)` should be inside the initialize method. Correct it.

Comment: The first "issue" you mention is not actually an issue. It's perfectly fine to leave out the type parameters of an expression, if the compiler can infer them based on the target type. (Search for `java diamond operator`.)

Comment: Yeah! @fabian I get that. Thanks for the info :)